# How can I stop slider video while its hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Ok so here I have a simple slider with few pictures and one video. Nothing fancy**

```
 <div class="slider-wrapper--default">
                    <div class="slider slider--default">
                        <div class="slider__item">
                            <div class="hero">
                                <div class='embed-container'>
                                  <img data-vimeo="unmute" id="volume" src="{image_dir}/icons/volume_off.svg" class="video" style="width:60px!important">
                                  <div class="transparent" style="z-index: 999; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;" data-toggle="modal" data-controls="video" data-target="#video-hp"></div>
                                  <iframe id="video" class="slider__item__bg" {if $en}src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/533585800?title=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&background=1&quality=1080p'{else}src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/533585695?title=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&background=1&quality=1080p'{/if}frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen allow="autoplay"></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slider__item">
                            <div class="hero">
                                {*
                                <div class="slider-overlay-text text-white">
                                    <h1>{f e="Everything begins with choice…" c="Vše začíná volbou…"}</h1>
                                    <hr class="divider divider--white s-pb-30 s-mt-25">
                                    <h6 class="text-uppercase text-center type-5">{if $en}„Happiness is not a matter of intensity but balance,<br class="d-block d-md-none"> order, rhythm and harmony.“ <br>Thomas Merton{else}„Štěstí není otázkou intenzity, ale rovnováhy,<br class="d-block d-md-none"> pořádku, rytmu a harmonie.“ <br>Thomas Merton{/if}</h6>
                                </div>
                                *}
                                <img class="slider__item__bg d-none d-lg-block" src="{content_url}/images/pages/homepage/0.0_Homepage_01a.jpg"
                                 alt="The Oaks Prague">
                                <img class="slider__item__bg d-block d-lg-none" src="{content_url}/images/pages/homepage/0.0_Homepage_01a.jpg"
                                 alt="The Oaks Prague">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slider__item">
                            <div class="hero">
                                <img class="slider__item__bg d-none d-lg-block" src="{content_url}/images/pages/homepage/0.0_Homepage_01b.jpg"
                                 alt="The Oaks Prague">
                                <img class="slider__item__bg d-block d-lg-none" src="{content_url}/images/pages/homepage/0.0_Homepage_01b.jpg"
                                 alt="The Oaks Prague">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slider__item">
                            <div class="hero">
                                <img class="slider__item__bg d-none d-lg-block" src="{content_url}/images/pages/homepage/0.0_Homepage_01c.jpg"
                                 alt="The Oaks Prague">
                                <img class="slider__item__bg d-block d-lg-none" src="{content_url}/images/pages/homepage/0.0_Homepage_01c.jpg"
                                 alt="The Oaks Prague">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**And then I have this jQuery script here. You can move the slider left and right. So what I am trying to achieve is that when the video slide is out of screen, it stops until you move to it again and then it plays again. Any idea how to do that?**

```
<script>
        
        
        $("[data-vimeo=unmute]").click(function() {
        var player = new Vimeo.Player($("#video")[0]);
        if (document.getElementById("volume").src == "https://c.oaksprague.cz/images/icons/volume_on.svg") 
            {
                document.getElementById("volume").src = "https://c.oaksprague.cz/images/icons/volume_off.svg";
                player.setMuted(true);
            }
            else 
            {
                document.getElementById("volume").src = "https://c.oaksprague.cz/images/icons/volume_on.svg";
                player.setMuted(false);
            }
        });
        
        $("[data-controls=video]").click(function() {
        var player = new Vimeo.Player($("#video")[0]);
        var player2 = new Vimeo.Player($("#video2")[0]);
        player.pause();
        
        });
        
        $("[data-close=video]").click(function() {
        var player = new Vimeo.Player($("#video")[0]);
        var player2 = new Vimeo.Player($("#video2")[0]);
        player.play();
        
        });
        
        
    </script>
```

Comment: How does this slider work? I can't see any code in the question that would cause the video to leave the screen.

Comment: Where is the script for your slider ?